# Optimizing code for more clearness and efficiency

Tags: java, optimization, performance

This code works fine, but I need to simplify it for more clearness and hopefully more efficiency:

```
int i = 0;

if (p.cap()) n++;
if (p.creditcard()) n++;
if (p.email()) n++;
[...]
if (p.price()) n++;
if (p.url()) n++;
if (p.zip()) n++;

if (n == 0) p.standard();
```

As the code says, I need to call multiple methods (I don't know the finite number of them). Every *p.*()* method returns a boolean value, and *n* is incremented only if the value returned is true. If n==0 (this happens when EVERY method called returns false) then I need to call *p.standard()*.

How can I write a more clear and efficient code? I tried with the *or condition*, something like this:

```
if (!( p.cap() || p.email() || p.isbn() || p.number() || p.phone() ||
       p.price() || p.time() || p.url() || p.zip() || p.creditcard()
    )) {
        p.standard();
}
```

But obviously it didn't work properly (example: if p.cap() returns true the other methods are not called).

**I need to call every method.**

Comment: maybe: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: The java compiler usually does a lot of optimization, so I would keep a piece of code like this rather readable than short.

Comment: Why do you say that the second example doesn't work properly? If the other methods are not called, isn't this the optimization you are expecting?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo It doesn't work properly because I need to call also the other methods.

Comment: Why do you *need* to call the other methods?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo Unfortunately I have to. It may vary, i.e.: in a function I call only 4 methods, in an other function I call 10 methods etc., but the mechanism is the same.

Comment: If you want to migrate, just flag and ask a mod to do it.  Please don't crosspost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not specify if every method *has* to be called, but it seems you want to call them all regardless of individual results. So use the simple or operator: | (not the short 
circuit or ||).

```
if (!( p.cap() | p.email() | p.isbn() | p.number() | p.phone() |
   p.price() | p.time() | p.url() | p.zip() | p.creditcard()
    )) {
        p.standard();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With some boilerplate, you could abstract this into some sort of validator interface:

```
interface Validator {
    boolean validate(Foo p);
}

Validator[] validators = new Validator[] {
    new Validator() { boolean validate(Foo p) {return p.cap();} },
    new Validator() { boolean validate(Foo p) {return p.creditcard ();} },
    new Validator() { boolean validate(Foo p) {return p.email();} },
    // …
}

public int validateAll(Foo p, Validator[] validators) {
    int valid = 0;
    for (Validator v : validators) {
        if (v.validate(p)) valid++;
    }
    return valid;
}

if (validateAll(p, validators)) p.standard();
```

This is a net increase in code, but it has the advantage of communicating "run all these checks on `p`" clearly, and the list of checks is extensible.

(I admit this might easily be a solution that's way too heavy for your needs.)

Answer (score 2):

really hard to do here - not enough context...

but make a new method on the p object that returns the value you are looking for... then call it from the place where all this code is now.

something like

```
int n = p.getPopulatedColumns();
```

then inside that method, it doesnt matter that much what the implementation is - because the reader will know the intent.

Answer (score 2):

There is another quite elegant solution IMO.

Create a validate method like this:

```
public static int validate(boolean ... booleans) {
    int n = 0;
    for (boolean b : booleans) {
        if (b) n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Then you can call this method like this:

```
int n = validate(p.cap(), p.creditcard(), p.email());
if (n == 0) p.standard();
```

Since the validate method takes the booleans as variadics you can add as many (or as few) arguments as you want.

Or maybe you can simplify to return a boolean if all arguments are false:

```
public static boolean validate(boolean ... booleans) {
    int n = 0;
    for (boolean b : booleans) {
        if (b) n++;
    }
    return 0 == n;
}
```

That all depends on if you need the `n` variable later on or not.