# Generics in Java: How do I make this example work?

Tags: java, generics

```
class main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  int[] array = new int[3];
  array[0]=3;
  array[1]=2;
  array[2]=1;
  System.out.println(<Integer>countGreaterThan(array,1));
 }
 static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
 int count = 0;
 for (T e : anArray)
    if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
        ++count;
    return count;
 }
}
```

I got this examle in [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html). When i write extends Comparable, how can i tell the compiler what is  type?
I think  i should instantiate T in `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, but how?

Comment: you can't use generics with primitive types like int, boolean, char, etc.... you have to use the object wrapper classes (as people have already mentioned).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change the `int` to `Integer` and remove that ugly `<Integer>` inside your print statement.

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[3];
array[0] = 3;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 1;
System.out.println(countGreaterThan(array, 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would arrange this so you can use varargs

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T elem, T... anArray) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
    }
}

System.out.println(countGreaterThan(1, 3,2,1));
```

Comment: @maba It also hides the ugliness of having to use `Integer` instead of `int`

Comment: Yes that is great. I had another elegant (IMO) solution in another question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244080/optimizing-code-for-more-clearness-and-efficiency/11245449#11245449)) but it didn't get much attention...

Answer (score 0):

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
  Integer[] array = new Integer[3];
  array[0]=3;
  array[1]=2;
  array[2]=1;
  System.out.println(countGreaterThan(array,1));
 }

    static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
        int count = 0;
        for (T e : anArray)
            if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
                ++count;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[3];   
    array[0]=3;   
    array[1]=2;   
    array[2]=1;   
    System.out.println(countGreaterThan(array,1));
```

Is this what you are looking for?